# yii update one attribute without using model save

Tags: php, yii

I need update the attribute count ($file->count) in the file model, as i have set the aftersave() function about this file model. when I update other file's attributes do save() model it will call the aftersave() later.

But when update the count attribute and save(), it need skip the aftersave().

How can I do it, Can I only save the count attribute without use save(), or set the condition on the aftersave() to skip the aftersave()

Comment: can you add a bit of your model and controller code ?

Comment: Thanks, the first answer solved my problem.

Comment: @JesseSiu : If first answer solved your problem. Then, please tick it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use saveAttributes method.

> Saves a selected list of attributes. Unlike save, this method only saves the specified attributes of an existing row dataset and does NOT call either beforeSave or afterSave. Also note that this method does neither attribute filtering nor validation. So do not use this method with untrusted data (such as user posted data). You may consider the following alternative if you want to do so:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#saveAttributes-detail